# Why it doesn't work, The Console program converts to Windows Form C #

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program to read telemetry from the game after UDP; in the console version, it works perfectly. I want to make a Windows Forms version, and I have no idea how to force it to work. Theoretically, I think it should work.
Sorry for maybe a trivial question; I'm a beginner.

Console Program:

```
namespace F12021
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            F12020TelemetryClient client = new F12020TelemetryClient(20777);
            client.OnCarTelemetryDataReceive += TelemetryUpdate;

            client.OnConnectStatusChanged += OnConnectStatusChange;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void OnConnectStatusChange(bool connected)
        {
            if (!connected)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Listening for F1 2020...");
            }
        }

        private static void TelemetryUpdate(PacketCarTelemetryData packet)
        {
            int playerIndex = packet.Header.playerCarIndex;
            CarTelemetryData playerData = packet.carTelemetryData[playerIndex];
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

            WriteLine($"Throttle: {playerData.throttle}");
        }

        private static void WriteLine(string input)
        {
            Console.Write(input.PadRight(Console.WindowWidth, ' '));
        }
    }
}
```

Windows Form:

```
namespace F1_2021
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
       
       
        public Form1()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            F12020TelemetryClient client = new F12020TelemetryClient(20777);
            client.OnCarTelemetryDataReceive += TelemetryUpdate;
            client.OnConnectStatusChanged += OnConnectStatusChange;
        }

        private void OnConnectStatusChange(bool connected)
        {
            if (!connected) { label1.Text = "Not conected wait....."; }
            else {  label1.Text = "Conected"; }
        }

        private void TelemetryUpdate(PacketCarTelemetryData packet)
        {
             
            int playerIndex = packet.Header.playerCarIndex;
            CarTelemetryData playerData = packet.carTelemetryData[playerIndex];
            label2.Text = (playerData.throttle).ToString() ;

        }
    }
}
```

What do I not understand?

Comment: What means "doesn' t work" ?

Comment: *What do I not understand?* - at a guess, because you didn't store your `F12020TelemetryClient client` in anything that will live longer than the end of the `Form_Load` method it's been disposed of shortly after the Form appeared on screen and is hence not a thing any more; no client -> no connection, no connection -> no updating your label. Perhaps store it as a class wide variable and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your console application, the `F12020TelemetryClient` instance is kept alive for as long as the application is running.

In your Windows Forms application, it's a local variable within the `Form_Load` method. As soon as that method ends, it's eligible for Garbage Collection. Make it a field of your class instead.

You'll also need to check whether the events are raised on the UI thread; if not, you'll need to marshal the calls to the UI thread before you can update any controls.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private F12020TelemetryClient _client;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client = new F12020TelemetryClient(20777);
        _client.OnCarTelemetryDataReceive += TelemetryUpdate;
        _client.OnConnectStatusChanged += OnConnectStatusChange;
    }

    private void OnConnectStatusChange(bool connected)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action<bool>)OnConnectStatusChange, connected);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!connected) { label1.Text = "Not conected wait....."; }
            else {  label1.Text = "Conected"; }
        }
    }

    private void TelemetryUpdate(PacketCarTelemetryData packet)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action<PacketCarTelemetryData>)TelemetryUpdate, packet);
        }
        else
        {
            int playerIndex = packet.Header.playerCarIndex;
            CarTelemetryData playerData = packet.carTelemetryData[playerIndex];
            label2.Text = (playerData.throttle).ToString() ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to move client to the top

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 
 F12020TelemetryClient client = new F12020TelemetryClient(20777);

 public Form1()
....
```

Comment: @CaiusJard I am really sorry, but the difference between your comment and my answer is less then a minute, plus they usually delay a  comment.  And I usually need several minutes to prepare the answer.  So I notised your comment after I published my answer.  And you can see my rating. I don't need '...it could be" , I know it. I just asked for something else

Comment: you should give an explanation as to why this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everything is already working correctly.

```
namespace F1_2021
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       
        F12020TelemetryClient client = new F12020TelemetryClient(20777);

        public Form1()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.OnCarTelemetryDataReceive += TelemetryUpdate;
            client.OnConnectStatusChanged += OnConnectStatusChange;
          
        }
 
        private void OnConnectStatusChange(bool connected)
        {
            label1.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
            {
                if (!connected) { label1.Text = "Not conected wait....."; }
                else { label1.Text = "Conected"; }
            }));
        }

        private void TelemetryUpdate(PacketCarTelemetryData packet)
        {
             
            int playerIndex = packet.Header.playerCarIndex;
            CarTelemetryData playerData = packet.carTelemetryData[playerIndex];
              label2.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
              {
                label2.Text = (playerData.throttle).ToString();
              }));       

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As this is almost identical to the answer given by Richard and accepted by you, why do you post this as additional answer?